# Can I upgrade from SQL Server 2016 13.0.5026.0 (X64) Standard Edition to Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) Enterprise Edition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, upgrade

I need to upgrade the SQL server installed on my server from 
SQL Server 2016 13.0.5026.0 (X64) Standard Edition **to** Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) Enterprise Edition
but I have got the below message
**the specified edition upgrade from source enterprise edition to target standard edition is not supported. for information about supported upgrade paths, see the sql server 2016 version and edition upgrade in books online.**

Answer (score 2):

In Production environment, the best way to deploy farm solution is using PowerShell command, VS usually used in test server for debug, in Production server,I would not suggest to install Visual Studio. And SharePoint Designer, usually is to develop custom master page and Client Side code for example, CSS, JavaScript, for C# solution, like web part, it is need to host with feature, and we can use PowerShell command below to deploy:

```
Add-SPSolution "[AgilePoint SharePoint Integration installation folder]\Ascentn.SharePoint.SettingsList.wsp"
Add-SPSolution "[AgilePoint SharePoint Integration installation folder]\AgilePoint.SharePoint.Dashboard.wsp"
Add-SPSolution "[AgilePoint SharePoint Integration installation folder]\Ascentn.SharePoint.WFIntegration.wsp"
Add-SPSolution "[AgilePoint SharePoint Integration installation folder]\Ascentn.SharePoint.ListForm.wsp"


Install-SPSolution -WebApplication "[Site Collection URL]" -GACDeployment 
        -FullTrustBinDeployment -Identity Ascentn.SharePoint.SettingsList.wsp 
        -CompatibilityLevel All
Install-SPSolution –WebApplication "[Site Collection URL]" -GACDeployment 
        -FullTrustBinDeployment -Identity AgilePoint.SharePoint.Dashboard.wsp 
        -CompatibilityLevel All
Install-SPSolution –WebApplication "[Site Collection URL]" -GACDeployment 
        -FullTrustBinDeployment -Identity Ascentn.SharePoint.WFIntegration.wsp 
        -CompatibilityLevel All
Install-SPSolution –WebApplication "[Site Collection URL]" -GACDeployment 
        -FullTrustBinDeployment -Identity Ascentn.SharePoint.ListForm.wsp 
        -CompatibilityLevel All

Enable-SPFeature -Url "[Site Collection URL]" -Identity AgilePointSettingsListFeature
Enable-SPFeature -Url "[Site Collection URL]" -Identity AgilePointDashboard
Enable-SPFeature -Url "[Site Collection URL]" -Identity AgilePointWFIntegration
Enable-SPFeature -Url "[Site Collection URL]" -Identity AgilePointListForm
```

Reference here:

[Add, Deploy, and Activate the SharePoint Solution Files with PowerShell](http://documentation.agilepoint.com/SupportPortal/DOCS/ProductDocumentation/CurrentRelease/DocumentationLibrary/maps/installDeployWspsPowerShellNxOnPrem.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ki Kerlos,

Based on a few things you have said it sounds like you have edited an already existing solution. Would this be correct?

If so you need to think about what you are deploying. If it is only code that you have updated (no new features, no new artefacts like pages content type or fields etc) you should be able to grab the WSP from your test env and run powershell command Update-SPSolution with the additional -GACDeployment and this should deploy your code.

If you are adding additional artefacts to an already existing feature you will need to do a feature upgrade [Chris o'Brian feature upgrades](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/06/feature-upgrade-part-1-fundamentals.html).

Cheers

Truez